# Number pyramid loops in c#

Tags: c#

If I wanted to modify a console app that currently prints:

> 1
>   12
>   123
>   1234

to print

> 1
>   121
>   12321
>   1234321

Which loop should i modify?
Below is the code from the original console app.

```
int altura; string space = ""; int cont2 = 0;
Console.Write("Dar altura: ");
altura = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = 1; i <= altura; i++)
{
    space = "";
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
        space = space + Convert.ToString(j);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(space);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just add an additional inner loop to count down. Seems like homework so I don't plan to write it for you but that should point you in the right direction

Comment: You just posted the answer people gave you before, without trying to change it. At least put some effort into it yourself. Are we going to see @Joel Coehoorn's answer as your next question and a new requirement from your homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
int altura; string space = ""; 
int cont2 = 0;
Console.Write("Dar altura: ");
altura = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = 1; i <= altura; i++)
{
    space = "";
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
        space = space + Convert.ToString(j);
    }
    for (int k = i - 1; k >= 1 ; k--)
    {
        space = space + Convert.ToString(k);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(space);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks! If I might ask, why does the second loop not overwrite the first assigned value of space in the first loop?

Comment: Because you join `space + Convert.ToString(k)` before assigning to `space`

Comment: You can also use `space += Convert.ToString(/*j or k*/);` in both loops

Answer (score 1):

```
int altura; string space = ""; int cont2 = 0;
Console.Write("Dar altura: ");
altura = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = 1; i <= altura; i++)
{
    var stack = new System.Collections.Generic.Stack<int>();
    space = "";
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
        space = space + Convert.ToString(j);
        stack.Push(j);
    }
    stack.Pop();
    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
       space = space + Convert.ToString(stack.Pop())
    }
    Console.WriteLine(space);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Or for fun:

```
int altura; 
Console.Write("Dar altura: ");
altura = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

var lines = Enumerable.Range(1, altura).Select(i =>
{
   var line = Enumerable.Range(1, i).ToArray();
   var reverse = line.Reverse().Skip(1).ToArray();
   return String.Join("", line.Concat(reverse).Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray())
});
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    Console.Writeline(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int rows=5;
            for(int i=1;i<=rows;i++){
                for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
                    Console.Write(" "+j);
                }
                for(int k=i-1;k>=1;k--){
                    Console.Write(" "+k);
                }
                 Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```